# increment years while looping in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

Is there a stored procedure which could do this??

TABLE A:

```
Column A- name
John 
Sam
Column B- year from:
2020
2021
Column C- year To: 
2025
2026
```

Table B:

```
Name 
Fiscalyear
```

I want to insert data into table B with entries for all years( previous table( year from - year to)
Output should look like

```
John 2020
John 2021
John 2022
John 2023
John 2024
John 2025
Sam 2021
Sam 2022
Sam 2023.... 
SAm 2026
```

Comment: It would make your example data much easier to understand if you showed it in tabular form, not each column separately.

Comment: Yes, you can do this with a stored procedure. It can use a loop that increments from `from` to `to` and inserts into `TableB`.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: MySQL version is ... ?